# Checking values within given standard deviations

Tags: statistics

Generate, both experimentally and theoretically what percentage of values of a random variable with normal distribution $N(0,1)$ lies in the boundaries of $+- 1.5$ standard deviation and $+- 2.5$ standard deviations.

So to do it experimentally, I generate a random variable with normal distribution but how do I then check what lies in a given spread of standard deviation? The standard deviation is around 1 here, of course, but how does it help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to take random variates from a standard normal distribution, then note that the standard deviation is $1$, so values that are within $1.5$ standard deviations of the mean of $0$ are simply $-1.5 \le Z \le 1.5$; in other words, just check if the values are between $-1.5$ and $1.5$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves the "experimentally" part, but how do I check the theoretical results, then? Won't they be just the same?

Comment: The theoretical result is what the z-table in the back of your book says it is.

Comment: Heh, maybe, but I'm training for my exam and I'm worried such answer won't satisfy the professor there :)